# Difference between two string of date JS

Tags: javascript, string, date, input

I tried to write code, which should do next:
When client come to a site he see two inputs with today date and date plus three days. In bottom the site will be a table with show how much days between two input's dates(sort of 1day, 2-3days,4-7days). I wrote the code which can set dates, but I can't set styles for elements by class.I'm a newest. Please any help.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var dFrom = document.querySelector('#my_lease_before');
  var dTo = document.querySelector('#my_lease_from');

    // get today date
    var dNow = new Date();
    // create var for add 3 days
    var dThen = new Date();
    // add 3 days
    dThen.setDate(dThen.getDate() + 3);

    // add value to inputes
    dTo.value = formatDate(dNow);
    dFrom.value = formatDate(dThen);

    //date-date=number, after make from millisec to days
    var dd = (dThen - dNow) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
   console.log(dd);
   // alert(dd);
    if (dd <= 1) {
      var s1 = document.querySelector('.space-1');
      s1.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s1.style.background = 'red';
      s1.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s1.style.color = 'white';
      s1.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    } else if (dd > 1 && dd <= 2) {
      var s2 = document.querySelectorAll('.space-2');
      s2.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s2.style.background = 'red';
      s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s2.style.color = 'white';
      s2.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    } else if (dd > 2 && dd <= 6) {
      var s3 = document.querySelectorAll('.space-3');
       s3.style.borderRadius = '50%' ;
       s3.style.borderRadius = '50%';
       s3.style.background = 'red';
       s3.style.display = 'inline-block';
       s3.style.color = 'white';
       s3.style.padding = '5px 2px';
 alert(s3);
    }else if (dd > 6 && dd <= 10) {
      var s4 = document.getElementsByClass('space-4');
      s4.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s4.style.background = 'red';
      s4.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s4.style.color = 'white';
      s4.style.padding = '5px 2px';
      
    }else if (dd > 10 && dd <= 16) {
      var s5 = document.getElementsByClass('space-5');
      s5.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s5.style.background = 'red';
      s5.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s5.style.color = 'white';
      s5.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    }else if (dd > 16 && dd <= 24) {
      var s6 = document.getElementsByClass('space-6');
      s6.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s6.style.background = 'red';
      s6.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s6.style.color = 'white';
      s6.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    }
  });


function formatDate(date) {
  //add zero for date before 10
  return [
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join('.');
  // delimiter
};

function parseDate(date) {
  var tmp = date.split('.');
  return new Date(tmp[2], tmp[1], tmp[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);

};
```

```html
<label>
 <span>rent from :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_from" id="my_lease_from">
</label>
<label>
 <span>rent to :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_before" id="my_lease_before">
</label>
<div class="my_price_gps">
    <span>GPS навигатор</span>
    <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>2 дня</th>
    <th>3-6 дней</th>
    <th>7-10 дней</th>
                         <th>11-16 дней</th>
    <th>17-24 дня</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="my_day_2"><span class="space-2">5 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_3"><span class="space-3">4 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_4"><span class="space-4">4 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_5"><span class="space-5">3 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_6"><span class="space-6">2 €</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="my_price_chair">
 <span>Детские<br/>автокресла</span>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="my_day_2"><span class="space-2">4 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_3"><span class="space-3">0 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_4"><span class="space-4">0 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_5"><span class="space-5">0 €</span></td>
    <td class="my_day_6"><span class="space-6">0 €</span></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: In addition, if i write this way var s3 = document.querySelectorAll('.space-3')[1]; , then print but only one of array

Comment: Please don't use comments to add information, edit the question. It's unclear what you are asking, do you just want to know how to style the elements? If so, that has nothing to do with javascript or dates. I'd suggest putting the style information into CSS classes, then just apply the appropriate class based on the value of *dd*.

Comment: In the parse function, `tmp[1]` should be `tmp[1]-1`.

Answer (score -1):

Use Like This 
To parse a date as UTC, append a Z - e.g.:

```
new Date('2011-04-11T10:20:30Z').
```

To display a date in UTC, use `.toUTCString(),`
to display a date in user's local time, use `.toString().`

[For More Details](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: For what? The format of date it's ok and string type too. The question is how to change style for .space-n classes in my code.

Comment: The OP seems to be asking "*… but I can't set styles for elements by class*", so nothing to do with Dates. If it was, it would be duplicate of one of the many parsing or formatting questions.